# LZ4N file format - file decoding

Tags: binary-analysis, file-format, firmware-analysis

I'm trying to decode a file that is part of device firmware. Unfortunately it comes RIFF<...>WAV format wrapped / packed with strange LZ4-like format.
Non of linux available lz4 tools do recognize this header.

Once below is unpacked it looks as by swapping bytes around, original eeprom binary can be recovered as the RIFF stream resembles expected firmware content.

File starts like this:

```
00000000: 6c7a 346e 0100 0000 0080 0000 40c8 ce01  lz4n........@...
00000010: f700 0000 f23c 5249 4646 38c8 ce01 5741  .....<RIFF8...WA
00000020: 5645 666d 7420 1000 0000 0100 0200 44ac  VEfmt ........D.
00000030: 0000 10b1 0200 0400 1000 6461 7461 14c8  ..........data..
00000040: ce01 72f8 1f4e 4943 0004 5936 8e95 6943  ..r..NIC..Y6..iC
00000050: 7272 7375 4c20 676f 6369 202c 6e49 2e63  rrsuL goci ,nI.c
00000060: 003a 0050 0104 0312 110c 0020 de21 0600  .:.P....... .!..
00000070: 0f02 0041 0088 002f 5252 8800 732f 5355  ...A.../RR..s/SU
00000080: 8800 730f 9801 ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ..s.............
00000090: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000a0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000b0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000c0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000d0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
000000e0: ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff ffff  ................
```

Does someone has an idea how to decode / unpack this?
Or even better could point to a tool? Linux lz4 tool doesn't like it - it creates different file headers...

Thanks